# In how many ways can we distribute 10 identical ice creams to 4 people so one of them gets a maximum of 4 ice cream?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know this formula should be used but I do not know how to apply the maximum part $\binom{n+r−1}{r−1}$

Edit:
Possible answers are: $\binom{8}{5}$,
$\binom{13}{10}$-$\binom{8}{5}$,$\binom{10}{4}$-$\binom{7}{4}$,$\binom{13}{4}$-$\binom{5}{4}$ or $\binom{10}{4}$-$\binom{6}{3}$

Edit2: since there are identical ice creams, some people may get 0 while one may even get 10. But one of them can get MAXIMUM 4.

Comment: Try subtracting ways when one person gets $5,6,7$ icecreams.

Comment: Yes but others can get 0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6 etc

Comment: Could $2$ people get $4$ ice creams each ?

Comment: I do not understand how this helps as I need to find all the ways. Can I get a more clear explanation?

Comment: When $a$=5, $b+c+d=5$ Now subcase $1$: $b,c,d\lt 4$   and sub case $2$: one of $b,c,d$ is $4$

Comment: In this problem, it's probably easiest to just list the cases.  Someone must get at least $3$ ice creams.  Just list the possibilities where the maximum is $3$ or $4$.  There isn't an easy formula like the one you quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using principle of inclusion and exclusion (PIE) is the easiest.

## if nobody gets more than 4 ice creams:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{10}{5}\right\rfloor}{\binom{4}{i}\binom{13-5i}{3}\left(
-1\right)^{i}}&=\binom{4}{0}\binom{13}{3}-\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{3}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{3}\\
&=68
\end{aligned}
$$

## if only one particular person cannot get more than 4 ice creams:

Say that person A cannot have more than 4. We want to count the number of distribution subtracted by number of distribution in which A get more than 4.

$$
\binom{13}{3}-\binom{8}{3}=230
$$

here, $\binom{8}{3}$ means we distribute 5 candies to 4 people then add 5 candies to person A. this way he always get more than 4.

You may want to read about this PIE, a very powerful tools in combinatorics.

Comment: are you sure, you got the right answer? Could you clarify how you are using PIE?

Comment: @Arcany when i posted the answer, i thought you want to know how to distribute with condition that nobody gets more then 4. is that correct or do u mean sh else?

Comment: No, one might get 10 while others get 0. But one of them may only get MAX. of 4. So one of them must get 0,1,2,3 or 4. How would you use PIE in that case?

Comment: @Arcany i edited the answer, pls check it out

Comment: Yeah $\binom{13}{10}$-$\binom{8}{5}$ is the right answer or as you have written it,$\binom{13}{3}$-$\binom{8}{3}$

Comment: Can you explain how you got that expression for the sum?

Comment: @h-squared $\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{3}$ means distributing 5 candies to 4 people and then adding another 5 candies to one of them, basically distribution in which at least one person have more than 4 candies. because of double counting, we need to subtract distribution in which 2 people get more than 4, which is $\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{3}$ i.e. distributing 0 candies and then giving 5 candies each to 2 person

Comment: @h-squared 68 is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ from Your expression in Your answer

Comment: what does $\binom{4}{0} \cdot \binom{13}{3}$. I know that it represents distributing $10$ candies to $4$ people but how do you use in overcounting

Comment: @h-squared that includes distribution in which nobody get more than 4 and distribution in which some may get more than 4. as i explained before, distribution in which some may get more than 4 is $\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{3}-\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{3}$ hence if i subtract this from $\binom{4}{0}\binom{13}{3}$ i get only distribution in which nobody get more than 4

Comment: Thanks a lot, but $\binom{8}{3} \cdot \binom{4}{1}$ is the ways where $1$ person gets more than $4$. Now this also includes when $2$ person gets more than $4$ so the event that $2$ persons get more than $4$ is counted only $1$ time, why do you use double counting then?

Comment: @h-squared when i count person A get more than 4, this may includes person B get more than 4. this will be counted again when i count person B get more than 4. double counting. for reference You may want to read about PIE

Answer (score 2):

An alternative can be:

Name the people $a,b,c,d$

Now we want solutions to the equation

$$a+b+c+d=10$$ where $0\leq a,b,c,d \leq 4$.

This is equivalent to finding the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the following expression:

$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^4$

The expansion can sometimes get ugly but this is better when there are restrictions for which there are many subcases.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening,

First, you have to decide which one of the people gets the maximum of 4 ice creams. You have $ p=4 $ possibilities for that. 
Therefore, you then just have to choose how to spread the 6 remaining ice creams among the 3 other people. This comes down to choose the places of the sticks "|" in the following expression :

```
            OO|O|OOO  (first has 2, second has 1 and third has 3)
```

For each stick, you have 7 different positions possible, so in total 7*7=49 possible configurations. *Then, you need to remove the permutations induced by the fact that the sticks are non-differentiable : stick 1 in position 3 and stick 2 in position 5 is the same than stick 1 in position 5 and stick 2 in position 3. To remove those cases, we can divide by 2!, the number of permutations of the sticks.*

In the end, since you had 4 possibilities for the guy getting the 4 ice creams, this leads to (49/2)*4=98 choices.

Hope this helps,

**Edit : ** my misstake, are you looking for :

- the number of cases where one get exactly 4 ice creams ?
- the numer of cases when one of the guys gets max 4 ice creams ?
- the number of cases where any of the guys gets max 4 ice creams ?

In all cases, it can be done with the previous technique I gave you, by counting different cases.

Edit2 : 
Corrected the number of permutations with the sticks according to comments (thanks ! ). And it seems this case corresponds to what has been asked.

Comment: It is also possible that a person doesnt get any icecream.

Comment: yeah exactly and this corresponds to a case like OO||OOOO (second has no ice cream)

Comment: Yeah, maximum 4 ice creams. It is like one of them gets maximum, others can get 0-10

Comment: Doing it this way allows the second person to get all $6$ ice creams$

Comment: @AymanMakki Your stars and bars part is incorrect. there are only 28 ways to divide 6 ice cream to 3 people. hint: $7^{2}$ is if Your sticks are distinguishable

Comment: @saulspatz yes indeed, it seems that this is allowed by the problem

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja thank you, you are totally right , I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since there are $4$ people and $10$ ice creams, someone must get at least $3$, so the maximum anyone gets is either $3$ or $4$.  The possible patterns when the maximum is $3$ are $$3,3,3,1\\3,3,2,2$$  The possible patterns when the maximum is $4$ are $$4,4,2,0\\4,4,1,1\\4,3,3,0\\4,3,2,1\\4,2,2,2$$ 
Now you just have to figure out how many ways each of these patterns can arise and add them up.

Usually, there are too many cases fo this to be a practical procedure, but I think it's the best way for this problem.